# Replacing multiline with sed

Tags: sed

I want to replace

```
@Column("uuid", {
   primary: true,
   name: "id",
   default: () => "uuid_generate_v4()",
})
```

with

```
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn
```

in a file with the following content:

```
export class SomeClass {
  @Column("uuid", {
    primary: true,
    name: "id",
    default: () => "uuid_generate_v4()",
  })
  id: string;

  @Column("timestamp with time zone", {
    name: "created_at",
    default: () => "now()",
  })
  created_at: Date;

  @Column("timestamp with time zone", {
    name: "updated_at",
    default: () => "now()",
  })
  updated_at: Date;

  @Column("uuid", { name: "other_id", unique: true })
  other_id: string;
}
```

This is my current solution:

```
sed -E -i '' -e '/@Column\(\"uuid\", \{/,/\}\)?/c  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn\(\"uuid\"\)' fileName
```

It basically works, but it's too inaccurate and also replaces other lines that shouldn't be replaced. I tried to add `uuid_generate_v4()` but couldn't get it to work, probably because of the line breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/@Column("uuid"/{:a;N;/^\s*})$/M!ba;/"uuid_generate_v4()/s/.*/@PrimaryGeneratedColum/}' file
```

Gather up lines between those containing `@Column("uuid"` and `})` and if those lines also contain `uid_generate_v4()`, replace all them by `PrimaryGeneratedColum`.